# What are the factors that decide which type of SPDC (Type I or II) occurs in a Non-Linear Crystal?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics, photonics

I have been reading through some literature on the theory of Spontaneous Parametric Down conversion (SPDC), their types, the phase-matching condition, etc. To my understanding, the downconverted signal and idler photons are generated when both the phase-matching condition, and energy conservation law are satisfied. Given we incident the pump at an angle $\theta_p$ to the optical axis of a uniaxial crystal, we can find the angles at which the signal and idler photons are generated for a given combination of the frequencies of the pump, signal, and idler (such that energy conservation holds).

Does that mean, the phase-matching condition can be satisfied for any given $\theta_p$, and frequencies of the photons (For both Types)? What are the factors that decide which type of SPDC takes place?

https://www.newlightphotonics.com/SPDC-Components/BBO-SPDC-Crystals
The crystals given in this site show crystals cut for specific types of SPDC with SPDC angles. How do the manufacturers control the type of down-conversion that is taking place?

Comment: If you are looking for the non-collinear phase matching conditions, the plots inside following paper seem to suggest that it is possible to achieve phase matching for a plethora of incident wavevector orientations (i.e. $\theta_p$): https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/optical-engineering/volume-39/issue-04/0000/Calculating-characteristics-of-noncollinear-phase-matching-in-uniaxial-and-biaxial/10.1117/1.602464.full

Comment: "Does that mean...". By setting $\theta_p$ you set constraints in the problem (both pump photon energy and k-vector) and SPDC only takes place for phase-matched frequencies, in certain directions. Its not arbitrary. You constraint the energy conservation and then due to refractive index only certain directions allow those frequencies to have a k-vector that fits momemtum conservation. Try to read more books on nonlinear optics, phase-matching curves etc. Also check SNLO software.